# Has the routing syntax changed a lot on Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Haven't play around for Rails one year.

I just want to craft an nested API by doing this and got a undefined method `namespace' exception.
I'm pretty sure this was working on Rail4 and 5.1

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::V1::CalculationRecordsController):
```

## route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # resources :controllers
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
      resources :calculation_records
    end
  end
end
```

## controller

```
    class Api::V1::CalculationRecordController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @records = CalculationRecord.all
      end
    end
```

[image]

I will be surprised if Rails is not supposing this syntax anymore LOL

Comment: hey, i updated the exception. sorry about that!

Comment: Rename your controller to 'CalculationRecordsController' as it is currently 'CalculationRecordController'

Comment: And rename the file to `calculation_records_controller.rb` All controller names and controller file names should be in plural form to work automagically

Answer (score 1):

```
class Api::V1::CalculationRecordController < ApplicationController
```

Make sure the controller file name is calculation_records_controller.rb and change `class Api::V1::CalculationRecordController` to `class Api::V1::CalculationRecordsController`

Answer (score 0):

```
module Api::V1
  class FilesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render json: {message: "files"}
    end
  end
end
```

or

```
class Api::V1::FilesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @records = render json: {message: "files"}
  end
end
```

and inside routes

```
resources :files, only: [:index]
```

Make sure you maintain the exact controller name